# PowerShell transfer script to exclude some files on holidays

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, file-transfer

I have a powershell script that transfers multiple files from one server to another using the Copy-Item cmdlet. I have a scheduled job to run Mon-Friday once a day. I cant kill the task because some files will still need to be transferred. However I would like to exclude say American holidays for other files in the script. How would I exclude the below file from being transferred on American holidays, while allowing file KEEP to be transferred?

```
   # 

   $date = get-date -format yyyy_MM_dd
   #
   #Transfer file to SFTP server
   Copy-Item "D:\ftproot\xxx\Archive\file_$($date)_17_00_00.csv" -destination "D:\ftproot\Files\" -force
   Copy-Item "D:\ftproot\xxx\Archive\KEEP_$($date)_17_00_00.csv" -destination "D:\ftproot\Files\" - 
   force
```

exit

Comment: Well, first you'll have to obtain or define a list of American holiday dates.

Comment: Example of holidays being exclude the below from file

Comment: Holiday 2020
New Years Day 2020/01/01
Martin Luther King, Jr. Day 2020/01/20
Washington's Birthday 2020/02/17
Good Friday 2020/04/10
Memorial Day 2020/05/25
Independence Day 2020/07/04
Labor Day 2020/09/07

Comment: Alright, you know which days you want to exclude - do you need help figuring out how to test whether today's date is one of these, or... something else?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the days I want to exclude to the D:\ftproot\xxx\Archive\file_$($date)_17_00_00.csv example on say dec 25th

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of strings describing the upcoming holiday dates in the same format as for the file, all you need to do if test whether *today's* date is contained in that list:

```
$Holidays = @(
  "2020_01_01"  # New Years Day
  "2020_01_20"  # Martin Luther King, Jr. Day
  "2020_02_17"  # Washington's Birthday
  "2020_04_10"  # Good Friday
  "2020_05_25"  # Memorial Day
  "2020_07_04"  # Independence Day
  "2020_09_07"  # Labor Day
)

$date = get-date -format yyyy_MM_dd

if($Holidays -notcontains $date){
  # Not a holiday, let's copy the file
  Copy-Item "D:\ftproot\xxx\Archive\file_$($date)_17_00_00.csv" -destination "D:\ftproot\Files\" -force
}

# This one gets copied regardless
Copy-Item "D:\ftproot\xxx\Archive\KEEP_$($date)_17_00_00.csv" -destination "D:\ftproot\Files\" -force
```